# Slide up when clicking on arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide

I want the content to show then when I click on the arrow it slides upward so it hides it and when they click it again it slides it down. This my code so far but this just keeps bringing it up without bringing it down.

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$("#a_main_content").hide();
$('.arrow').click(function(){

$("#a_main_content").slideToggle();
$(".arrow").show();
});

var value = 180
$(".arrow").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=180;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     } 

});

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <!Doctype>
<head>
  <!-- <link type="text/css" href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />    

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/Box_Toggle.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
     <div id="main_header">  
     <div id="main_header_wrapper">
     <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Chattrd"/>

     <nav id="navigation"><b>
     <a href="#" class="nav_icon">Home</a>
     <a href="#" class="nav_icon">Forum</a>
     <a href="#" class="nav_icon">Login</a>
     <a href="#" class="nav_icon">Register</a>
     </b></nav>

     </div>
     </div>

     <div id="content_background">
     <div id="content_header">
     <b> Announcements </b>
     <img src="images/arrow.png" class="arrow">
     </div>
     <div id="a_main_content">
     <center><b><u>We are coming very soon</u></b></center>
     Please stand by, we are coming soon
     </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/KurUa/

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/KKY7e/

Comment: No I need it too show it first not hide it.

Comment: Pointing out some problems here. You're loading the `jQuery UI` library before the `jQuery` one itself. The `<b>` tag shouldn't have `anchors` within it, but the other way round or you can use `CSS` to achieve the same result. Last, where are you getting the `jQueryRotate.js` and `Box_Toggle.js` files from? You should place them here so we can test your code.

Comment: @JamesNixon, wait what are you trying to hide?